# The “correct” answer to an opinion or help question

Tags: discussion

Not once or twice will you find question on MESE that cannot have a single objective answer to mark with the green checkmark.
questions like  [What are the best practices for giving online tests?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18477) and many more like it.
as much as half of the questions on MESE are like this, if it isn't the "correct" answer, what should we give the green checkmark to?

Comment: Relevant link: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I just came across these earlier Meta discussions related to accepting answers: [Accepting answered questions difficult](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32) and [Community votes versus accepted answers](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302)

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the green tick mark is to indicate which answer helped the question asker the most. It is not intended to mark the objectively best answer. So, askers can be encouraged to accept the answer they find the most helpful. It is also perfectly fine to not accept any answer, especially when the question is a "list question".

You can also take a look at the FAQ on Meta SE: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

> ### What does it mean to accept an answer?
>
> The system allows you to mark an answer as "accepted", in order to indicate which answer solved your problem or most thoroughly answered your question in the end. Accepting an answer is important as it rewards posters for correctly answering your question, informs others that your issue is resolved, and pins the answer to the top so others reading your question read that answer first.
>
> ...
>
> ### Which answer should I accept?
>
> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - Otherwise, even if there are answers that are good enough but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.
> - Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is also good for others to follow. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact not the perfect way.
> - **The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.**

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In theory, "opinion-based" questions, here, and at many other stacks, are off-topic. That leads to an issue. Unlike the Math stack, where equations are solved and answers are facts (I hope), here, the "best practice" question should be welcome, and usually is.
Members are encouraged to choose their accepted answer as a 'thank-you' to the member who helped. I've seem comments elsewhere, "you've asked a dozen questions, and not 'accepted' any of the answers to any of them."

I'd suggest the member asking such a question choose the one that helped them most. I also think that votes speak for themself, although I've seen wrong answers highly voted, but most often, votes reflect quality of an answer. (And, to your point, it's also ok to occasionally skip 'accepting' an answer.)